# Why would an emitter follower be DC-coupled to its input?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, npn, emitter-follower, common-collector

In my experience, an emitter-follower amplifier is usually AC-coupled to both its input and output:

[image: schematic]

However, I recently came across such an amplifier which is DC-coupled - the capacitors C1 and C2 are replaced by resistors:

[image: schematic]

This circuit is used for a video signal - Vin is a 1.5Vp-p signal that comes from a DAC, and Vout should be a 0.7Vp-p 75 Ohm signal.

How does the behaviour of this amplifier differ from the AC-coupled version?

Is DC-coupling less robust than AC-coupling? For example, will the amplifier only work if the input signal has a certain DC offset? Does it require the DAC to have a particular output impedance?

Why might the designer have chosen to DC-couple this amplifier rather than use the more robust AC-coupling?

Comment: "*Why might the designer have chosen to DC-couple this amplifier rather than use the more robust AC-coupling?*" Well, the advantage of a DC-coupled amplifier is that it can pass DC. Can you guess what a video signal is? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_video

Comment: The designer knows the output characteristics of the DAC in terms of voltage. He just wants the emitter follower as a current gain stage. For a given DAC value, he knows what the resultant Vout will be. No need to AC couple as there are no unknown DC offsets. AC coupling is not necessarily more 'robust' - definitely more common in audio applications though.

Comment: Please show an actual circuit inside a product where a capacitively coupled emitter follower is used. It seems to me that your experience of these types of circuit might be questionable thus invalidating the reason for asking.

Comment: The key is what is the role of the capacitors in the circuit you understand?

Answer (score 2):

For an NPN transistor, its emitter voltage \$V_E\$ is 0.7V lower than its base voltage \$V_B\$, so that \$V_E = V_B - 0.7V\$. This means that the emitter follower has a gain of 1, and the amplitude of Vout is the same as the amplitude of Vin. The output is merely offset by -0.7V with repect to the input.

Since the output cannot drop below 0V, the base cannot drop below 0.7V without clipping. If you can be sure that your input signal will always lie in the range \$0.7V \le V_{IN} \le V_{CC}+0.7V \$, then you may tie the input directly to the base, and you do not even require R3. In fact, even biasing with R1, R2 is unnecessary.

With such a constrained input, where DC coupling is possible, you avoid the consequences of AC coupling, such as high-pass filtering, phase shift, settling time, and the need for a (potentially large) capacitor and biasing resistors.

The need for C2 at the output depends on the biasing requirements of the next stage, and doesn't really fall under the the responsibility of this circuit. If, by chance, the ouput of this emitter follower happens to be exactly correctly biased for whatever comes next, you may not need C2.

An NPN emitter-follower is able to source current with very low impedance (since the transistor is able to raise the output voltage high very easily), but the only way it can sink current is via the emitter resistance. The statement that the circuit has an output impedance of 75Ω is dependent on how you connect the load. It would be more accurate to say it has an output impedance of 1kΩ. R4 seems to be redundant, and would only be necessary if the output load somehow required it to be.

Answer (score 2):

Since the application is a video signal amplifier, and the signal characteristics that are to be amplified are known, it is really the best solution to simply use DC coupling for video signals.

AC coupling of video signal is really a hassle, as the frequencies of interest must go down to very low frequencies and the removal of DC components mean that the circuit must have some kind of DC restoration circuit meaning clamping of sync pulses to somewhat known level before the amplifier input.